# Continuity of "dotted" function

Tags: general-topology, continuity

$f(x)=1$; $f:\{1,2\} \rightarrow \{1\}$ apparently this function is continous. But we can't neither argue with a $\delta-Neighbourhood$ nor with two sided $lim_{+-}$. What would be the right approach here? Thanks!

Comment: Where did this question come up? In any topological space, the constant functions are continuous, but the tools from analysis aren't really suited to tacking questions about finite spaces

Comment: i thought of it on my own. But topologically we still do not have a neighbourhood, do we ?

Comment: this is a metric space, but we cant find an epsilon ball

Comment: If we have a topology, then we have neighbourhoods. If we don't have a topology, we can't speak of continuity.

Comment: @Sten, you can think of the set $\{1,2\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For continuity proof any $\delta$ is good (e.g. $\delta=1$).

Comment: @Kulisty but f is not defined for x+delta there is nothing

Comment: @Kulisty Sure, we can define a topolgy that way, and it gives us the discrete topology on $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$. I'd still tend to think that we'd be in "when all you have is a hammer" territory

Comment: @Maths, Remember that the neighbourhood in epsilon-delta definition of continuity is restricted to points from the domain of the function.

Comment: Still, I agree that this is not the best tool to tackle finite spaces.

Comment: |x-x0|<delta lets take x0=1, the only x that satisfies it would (if we take delta<1) x0 itself

Comment: True, why is it a problem?

Comment: yeah, youre right. As the defiinition tells us for every x of domain, and if x0 is the only x of domain, it satisfies the condirion. thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches based on point set topology come to mind, which feel more natural than an approach based on analysis

1. If the topology you give $X = \{1, 2\}$ is the one induced from $\mathbb{R}$, then you end up with the discrete topology, so that the open sets are $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}\}$. Using the "open-set" definition of continuity, can you show that all functions from a discrete space to any topological space are continuous? Open-set continuity: a function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous iff for any open set $V$ of $Y$, the set $\{x | f(x) \in V\}$ is open in $X$.
2. The function you've chosen is constant. An equivalent definition of continuity is the closed-set definition, where a function $f: X\to Y$ is continuous iff for any closed set $C$ of $Y$, the set $\{x | f(x) \in C\}$ is closed in $X$. Using this definition, can you show that all constant between two topological spaces are continuous?